# VersionOne REST Query to obtain ToDo hours for defect

Tags: versionone

I want to get the total of ToDo hours for a version one Defect.  As I understand this is basically needing to sum all the subordinate tasks since hours are not explicitly tracked by defect assets.

This query will get me all the primary work items under estimates for epics:

```
rest-1.v1/Data/Epic?sel=Epic.ID.Number,SubsAndDown:PrimaryWorkitem.Estimate.@Sum&where=Epic.ID.Number='XXX'
```

I tried to modify above for Defects:

```
rest-1.v1/Data/Defect?sel=Epic.ID.Number,SubsAndDown:Task.ToDo.Value@Sum&where=Defect.ID.Number='XXX'
```

But this returns nulls and nothing of value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I figured it out:

```
rest-1.v1/Data/Defect?sel=Defect.ID.Number,ChildrenAndDown:Task.ToDo.@Sum&Where=Defect.Number='XXX'
```

It was a child not a sub! Easy to mix the two up...

Just to clarify, this will list all the remaining hours for tasks that are CHILDREN of the defect XXX.